# How to copy the first row of the query from SQL to a data grid view by C# button?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

This is an approximate code , And please help to make code better

```
private void btnBurger_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"server=.;database=test;integrated security=true");
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from items where Items_Name = 'Burger' ", cn); // After the query has a single row of the item name, price and quantity I want to show the row in datagridview
        DataTable Dt = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(Dt);
        dgv.Rows[0] =Dt.Rows[0] ;  // Error here
    }
```

Comment: is your query returning rows when you run it in SSMS?

Comment: Although people who are familiar will probably be able to guess your error, it's always useful to write the actual error not "Error here".

Comment: @Ahmed Hamdy check my answer and tell me if anything is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just change the data fetching line to get only first row like below (using `top 1` to fetch the first row; assuming that you are using SQL Server as DB)

```
SqlDataAdapter da = 
new SqlDataAdapter("select top 1 * from items where Items_Name = 'Burger' ", cn);
```

Then Bind it to the GridView like

```
    da.Fill(Dt);
    dgv.DataSource =Dt;
    dgv.DataBind(); //This line may not be necessary if it's a Winform app
```